# Issue with the coding mode

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse for PHP Developers Version: 3.0.2, today when I am coding, the mode seems changed, it looks like command mode, see below pic:
[image]

The normal mode should be like this:
[image]

if you see the status of cursor, you can see the difference. So my question is :

How could I change the first mode to the second one? I want to use the normal one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the cursor status press `Insert key`.

It will change the first mode in to second.